# Using Regex to delete multiple tags

Tags: java, regex, duplicates

I'm struggling with Regex . I'm getting a text that has multiple tags that I need to remove, but I can't find a good way of doing it.

This is my JAVA code: (It's pretty bad :P)

```
public static String DeleteExtras(String notes){    
    String regexLazy = "(<a id=\".*?\" name=\".*?\" shape=\".*?\"></a>)+?";
    String regexGreedy = "(<a id=\".*?\" name=\".*?\" shape=\".*?\"></a>)+";    

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexGreedy);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(notes);
    String match = notas;
    if (matcher.find()){
        match = matcher.group();
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(regexLazy);
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(notes);
        if (m2.find()){
            notes = notes.replace(match,m2.group());
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simplified version of the text I'm getting:

```
    <div class="tr_footnote">
    <p class="footnote">
        <a id="#(1)" name="#(1)" shape="rect"/>
        <a id="(1)" name="(1)" shape="rect"/>
        <a id="(1)" name="(1)" shape="rect"/>
        <a id="(6)" name="(6)" shape="rect"/>
        <a id="(8)" name="(8)" shape="rect"/>(1)</p>
</div>
<div class="tr_footnote">
    <p class="footnote">
        <a id="(2)" name="(2)" shape="rect"/>(2)</p>
</div>
<div class="tr_footnote">
    <p class="footnote">
        <a id="(7)" name="(7)" shape="rect"/>
        <a id="(7)" name="(7)" shape="rect"/>(7)</p>
</div>
<div class="tr_footnote">
    <p class="footnote">
        <a id="(8)" name="(8)" shape="rect"/>(8)</p>
</div>
```

I know my code doesn't work properly... 
So far what it does is delete the first set of repeated tags and I take the first apparition of  (a tag) as the valid one, So I replace the rest of them, for the first (a tag) (This is the first div in the example text) . The problem is that it doesn't work with the other repeated tags. I 've tried with  while( matcher.find() ) instead of if , but it replaces all the tags for the same one. I can't find a walkaround for this so far... :(

Thanks!

Comment: This is a job for a Parser...

Comment: omg when will this end. don't use regex to deal with html parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into XSLT. It's a language for transforming XML to--what else--more XML. It's slightly overkill for what you're doing, but only slightly.